# json to super in Redshift but the json has a lot of escaped characters

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a value in a Redshift super column that looks like this:

```
"[{\"id\": \"1031633456861079\", \"type\": \"High School\", \"selected\": true, \"displayName\": \"Tiverton High School - the \\\"unofficial page\\\"\"}, {\"id\": \"185210834836683\", \"type\": \"College\", \"selected\": true, \"displayName\": \"Southeastern Academy\"}]"
```

I want to store this without the escaped quotes. Notice the "unofficial page" has several escaped characters. What can I do here?

I have something like this:

```
SELECT
--     JSON_PARSE(NULLIF(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(JSON_SERIALIZE(after."educations"."string"), '\\', ''), '"[', '['), ']"', ']'), 'null')) AS education2,
```

but it's just not robust enough and the JSON_PARSE fails. This is user input. Does redshift have any way to convert this? Or... just ignore this on error?

Comment: Use TRIM() to remove the leading and trailing “ characters.  Your REPLACE() of the backslash should be fine.